# Images through the URL doesn't display

Tags: java, image, swing, url, embedded-resource

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class O2BIntro extends Open2Beat {
    
    private JLabel screenGraphic;
    
    private ImageIcon introBackground;
    private ImageIcon titleImage;
    private ImageIcon startButtonImg;
    private ImageIcon settingButtonImg;
    private ImageIcon buttonSelectedImg;
    
    public O2BIntro() {
        introBackground = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("../img/wp2537453-dj-background-hd.jpg"));
        titleImage = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("src/img/open2BeaTTitle.png"));
        startButtonImg = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("src/img/MenuImg_Gamestart_KR.png"));
        settingButtonImg = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("src/img/MenuImg_Preference_KR.png"));
        
    }
    
    public void paintIntro() {
        
        screenGraphic = new JLabel(introBackground,JLabel.CENTER);
        screenGraphic.setBounds(0, 0, DisplayBasic.myScreenWidth, DisplayBasic.myScreenHeight);
        add(screenGraphic);
    }
    
}
```

So, this is my current part of code. I tried to load my images from /src/img/, but it still doesn't display anything. How should I edit my code? Which kind of framework or component should I use to display properly?

Comment: The `getResource()` method will search directories on your classpath. So src/img must be defined on your classpath.

Comment: Try `"/img/open2BeaTTitle.png"` (**note leading `/`**) and report back.